# Adding ASP.NET MVC and Web API Web Application in same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i want to create .net mvc project but i also want to add wep api 
within the same project, do will i need a controller for api and a controller for a normal .net mvc ?
i have searched in google but i didn't find a helpful solution,
any answer will definitely help me 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1- Add webapiconfig.cs file in App_Start folder

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

2- In Global.ascs.cs file add the new line mentioned in the comment. Your Application_Start function should look like below.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);//new line for webapi
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

3- Now add a new apicontroller like below.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
        return Json("test");
    }
}
```

4- Api url will be like "http://localhost:61012/api/Test/GetAll"

5- Don't forget to add this nuget package : Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

Comment: Thank you very much helped me alot